# Recovering from NFS file

Tags: mount, hard-drive, data-recovery, nfs

I used to have a NAS storage (STOREX NAS-351). After a firmware upgrade, the system is unresponsive and won't get connected to the network.

I extracted the hard drive, a Western Digital Caviar SE 500 GB, and put it into a USB external case.

I am unable to access is when I plug it into my windows system. However, from an Ubuntu machine, it shows under /dev/sdb

Still, I cannot mount it. I tried with NTFS and I receive errors. I tried running TestDisk and the file type is not recognized.

Anybody has an idea on how to approach this?

Comment: What errors? What exactly does it show under /dev/sdb?

Comment: Try mounting as `ext3`/`ext4`

Answer (score -2):

Frst you need to make disk image. I recommend you OF Clone or CloneZilla. Then you can use R-Studio for data recovering. R-Studio has also option for image disk. Before you start please check Windows disk manager if disk is detected. If disk make strange noises then is hardware problem.